# What does a macro definition with the same token twice in C mean?

Tags: c, ruby

I was reading the [Ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) when I stumbled upon the following:

```
#define RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX
```

[context](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/973ba3e8e24f4497aebcbd3819fc9c0f38a7909f/include/ruby/ruby.h#L968)

As far as I can tell `RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX` is not defined before. (I grepped the Ruby source recursively).

What does that line do exactly?

Comment: It was originally `#define RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX ((int)((sizeof(VALUE)*3)/sizeof(char)-1))`. See the commit where it was changed: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/fd89a968372ca748910477dec8c5865e65a18565 I guess the macro was left for compatibility concerns?

Comment: oh I see..but wouldn't it make more sense to set it to 0? I'm not a C guru, so I don't know the best practices.

Comment: @matt It's still set to `(int)((sizeof(VALUE)*3)/sizeof(char)-1)`. But it's not a macro anymore, but an `enum`. I assume it was converted into an `enum`, to prevent common pitfalls with the evaluation of macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This define will expand into the literal token `RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX`, just as you would expect.

By looking at the source, you'll see, that the macro is used to define an `enum` value with the same name, set to `(int)((sizeof(VALUE)*3)/sizeof(char)-1)`.

The commit, linked by [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt), explains they converted all macros into enums, to improve debugging. And the macro was left for compatibility reasons.

Comment: So `#define RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX` it's rather poinless I suppose.

Comment: but where is RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX given a meaningful value (a number I suppose)?

Comment: and why do they write that #define, if it has no meaning?

Comment: @le_me It's given a meaningful name literally 4 lines down in the source code. They define an `enum` with the name.

Comment: oh enum variants are in the global namespace in C, I forgot that! Thank you, it makes sense now!